# SQL query to extract extension from middle of URL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to write a single SQL query for extracting file extension from URLs if  I have  URL is like this :

```
1) www.xyz.com\hello\world\fileA.txt?ID=01
2) www.xyz.com\hello\world\fileA.txt
```

Please help if anybody knows it

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? This kind of functionality is highly DBMS dependent

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Updated my post. Check out if this suits you.

Comment: Are you sure doing this in the database is the most sensible choice of tool for the job? There are lots of languages which have rich support for URL manipulation. T-SQL isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS T-SQL:

1) select SUBSTRING (URL, CHARINDEX('?', URL) - 3, 3)

2) select RIGHT(URL, 3)

so you could combine them as follows:

```
Select Case When CHARINDEX('?', URL) <> 0 Then SUBSTRING (URL, CHARINDEX('?', URL) - 3, 3)
       ELSE RIGHT(URL, 3)
       END as Extension
```

[CharIndex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[PatIndex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: hii sarin I have edited my question. I want to extract extension from both type of URL with a single query

Comment: it's not clear what you want to extract from the string? What do you want to end up with? When you say "extension from URLs", does this mean "?ID=01" or "fileA.txt" or "txt" ???

Comment: @r4sn4 I've just updated the answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
substring('www.xyz.com\hello\world\fileA.txt?ID=01',38,10)
```

Will return you 10 characters which are after "ID="

Read more about substring here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/eng-eng/library/ms187748.aspx

---

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN len(URL) = 33 THEN right(URL,3)
ELSE SUBSTRING(URL,31,3)
END
FROM #temp1
```

Comment: I just gave an example ...URL could be of any length.